# how to draw a half circle in android

Tags: android

I'm using this code to draw a half in my app:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >
    <item
        android:left="35dp"
        android:top="40dp"
        android:bottom="40dp"
        android:right="0dp">
        <shape
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="oval" android:innerRadius="30dp" android:thickness="0dp">
            <solid android:color="@color/transparent"/>
            <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="@color/White"/>

        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

output :

[image]

but i need something like below :

[image]

how to  draw this ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I would suggest to draw it through code.

1- Create class MyView and put below code.

```
public class MyView extends View {

    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        float width = (float) getWidth();
        float height = (float) getHeight();
        float radius;

        if (width > height) {
         radius = height / 4;
        } else {
         radius = width / 4;
        }

        Path path = new Path();
        path.addCircle(width / 2,
         height / 2, radius,
         Path.Direction.CW);

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

        float center_x, center_y;
        final RectF oval = new RectF();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

        center_x = width / 2;
        center_y = height / 2;

        oval.set(center_x - radius,
            center_y - radius,
            center_x + radius,
            center_y + radius);
        canvas.drawArc(oval, 90, 180, false, paint);
    }
}
```

2-Initialize this class inside you activity or fragment:-

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(new MyView(this));
}
```

Comment: @testStack Welcome mate.

Comment: Any ideas how to append semicirle to arc for instance? To have cap just from one side?

Comment: You add the lines of Path path = new Path();.... but you never use it....unnecessary

Answer (score 13):

Your can use a rectangle shape .xml file and edit the corners on one side only.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <size android:height="30dp"
        android:width="30dp"/>
    <solid android:color="@color/black"/>
    <corners android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: "Different corner sizes are not supported in Path.addRoundRect"

Answer (score 12):

You can use `<clip />` drawable in order to cut-off part of your circle.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Clip

Comment: Good, but not a complete answer. Answers should be able to stand by themselves, and only use links as support. The idea is when android moves the URL this answer will still work. That is not the case. As I have to go elsewhere to learn what a clip tag is.

Comment: @StarWind my link does not provide any ready-to-use tutorial which you must follow, it just points to the documentation which you need to read and understand. There would be no point in copying it to the answer itself as there would be a risk that it will become obsolete.

Comment: @DmitryZaitsev just pointing out Stack overflow guidelines. Take it up with SO if you don't agree with the rules.
http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 2):

this is how i created my semi circle in a drawable xml file.

```
<size
    android:width="180dp"
    android:height="90dp"></size>

<corners
    android:topLeftRadius="200dp"
    android:topRightRadius="200dp"></corners>
```

Comment: create a shape of rectangle
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

Comment: This creates a semi-circle. What OP wants is a curved line.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <size
        android:width="180dp"
        android:height="90dp"></size>

    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="200dp"
        android:topRightRadius="200dp"></corners>
    <stroke android:width="5px" android:color="@color/black" />
</shape>
```

Comment: add a description why and how this solves the problem described in the answer