# How to create half circle filled shape using xml drawable in android?

Tags: android, android-drawable, shapes

I want to create a half filled circle shape using xml drawble?

Like this [image]

Here is my efforts that i have tried so far

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#FCD83500"/>
    <size
        android:width="10dp"
        android:height="5dp"/>
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="50dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="50dp"/>
</shape>
```

Using above code i can create half circle but i don't know how to make half circle transparent

I have also visited some SO post but unable to find any solution

- [Half circle shape not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40043351/half-circle-shape-not-work)
- [how to draw a half circle in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31705870/how-to-draw-a-half-circle-in-android/31706849)
- [How to define a circle shape in an Android xml drawable file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185103/how-to-define-a-circle-shape-in-an-android-xml-drawable-file)

If need more information please do let me know. Thanks in advance. Your efforts will be appreciated.

Comment: Is it necessary to use xml drawable? Otherwise, you can use vector graphics as well.

Comment: @BalvinderSingh feel free to post solution using `vector graphics`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created code from Vector Graphics :

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="314.015"
    android:viewportHeight="314.015">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FCD83500"
        android:pathData="M157.007,0C70.291,0 0,70.289 0,157.007c0,86.712 70.29,157.007 157.007,157.007c86.709,0 157.007,-70.295 157.007,-157.007C314.014,70.289 243.716,0 157.007,0zM31.403,157.015c0,-69.373 56.228,-125.613 125.604,-125.613V282.62C87.631,282.62 31.403,226.38 31.403,157.015z" />
</vector>
```

Output will be:

[image]

Now if you want to display in as per your angle:

You can use as below:

```
android:rotation="90"
```

in your `ImageView`

### Update for `TextView` Drawable:

Create custom method for rotate drawable.

```
private Drawable rotate(Drawable drawable, int degree) {
    Bitmap iconBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(degree);
    Bitmap targetBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(iconBitmap, 0, 0, iconBitmap.getWidth(), iconBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);

    return new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), targetBitmap);
}
```

Use as below:

```
Drawable result = rotate(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.ic_round), 90);
yourTextView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(result, null, null, null);
```

> Note: If you will find SVG image as you want then you do now have to
> do above code. I have tried to find image but didn't found so Rotation
> code is necessary here.

Hope it will help you.

Thank you.

Comment: This is nice idea but i want use this inside a `TextView` as `android:drawableEnd` so i can't use  `android:rotation="90"`

Comment: @Goku Just try as above.

Comment: hey thanks for your time i have found how to rotate `vector` check my below answer +1 for your help

Comment: Here I have posted [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55038379/android-rotate-vector-image-to-90-degree) and got [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55038948/1318946).

Comment: thank you i have already checked your question, mean while you can update your answer, thanks for the help i will accept your answer

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

Use this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="90"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toDegrees="90">
    <vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="314.015"
        android:viewportHeight="314.015">
        <path
            android:fillColor="#FCD83500"
            android:pathData="M157.007,0C70.291,0 0,70.289 0,157.007c0,86.712 70.29,157.007 157.007,157.007c86.709,0 157.007,-70.295 157.007,-157.007C314.014,70.289 243.716,0 157.007,0zM31.403,157.015c0,-69.373 56.228,-125.613 125.604,-125.613V282.62C87.631,282.62 31.403,226.38 31.403,157.015z" />
    </vector>
</rotate>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Finally i got solution using  [**`layer-list`**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource#LayerList) to Achieve this

- A `LayerDrawable` is a `drawable` object that manages an array of other `drawables`. Each `drawable` in the list is drawn in the order of the list—the last `drawable` in the list is drawn on top.

**MY CODE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:left="26px"
        android:right="26px">

        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="oval"
            android:useLevel="false">
            <solid android:color="#00006AC5" />
            <size
                android:width="50dp"
                android:height="50dp" />
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#00BCD4" />
        </shape>

    </item>

    <item
        android:width="50dp"
        android:height="25dp"
        android:end="2dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:start="2dp"
        android:top="22dp">

        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#00BCD4" />
            <size
                android:width="10dp"
                android:height="5dp" />
            <corners
                android:bottomLeftRadius="50dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="50dp" />
        </shape>

    </item>

</layer-list>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

> **Note :** feel free to post answer if you have any other solution's

Comment: Warning : `Attribute end is only used in API level 23 and higher (current min is 16)`

Comment: I think you will get error : `Element vector is not allowed here`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:color="#FCD83500"
                android:width="1dp"/>
            <size
                android:width="20dp"
                android:height="20dp"/>
            <corners
                android:radius="50dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:top="10dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FCD83500"/>
            <size
                android:width="20dp"
                android:height="10dp"/>
            <corners
                android:bottomLeftRadius="50dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="50dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Thanks, but your code is not working please check the  [output using your code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0f2c.png)

Comment: @Goku have you checked it on a real device?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to make half circle vector image. if you want to rotate the vector image means use group tag with rotation element . Refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55038379/android-rotate-vector-image-to-90-degree/55038948#55038948)

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="24dp"
android:height="24dp"

android:viewportWidth="314.015"
android:viewportHeight="314.015">
<group
    android:translateX="314.015"
    android:rotation="90">
<path
    android:fillColor="#FCD83500"
    android:pathData="M157.007,0C70.291,0 0,70.289 0,157.007c0,86.712 70.29,157.007 157.007,157.007c86.709,0 157.007,-70.295 157.007,-157.007C314.014,70.289 243.716,0 157.007,0zM31.403,157.015c0,-69.373 56.228,-125.613 125.604,-125.613V282.62C87.631,282.62 31.403,226.38 31.403,157.015z" />

</group>
</vector>
```