# Android : Rotate Vector Image to 90 degree

Tags: android, vector, rotation, drawable

I have following code for my vector:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"

    android:viewportWidth="314.015"
    android:viewportHeight="314.015">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FCD83500"
        android:pathData="M157.007,0C70.291,0 0,70.289 0,157.007c0,86.712 70.29,157.007 157.007,157.007c86.709,0 157.007,-70.295 157.007,-157.007C314.014,70.289 243.716,0 157.007,0zM31.403,157.015c0,-69.373 56.228,-125.613 125.604,-125.613V282.62C87.631,282.62 31.403,226.38 31.403,157.015z" />
</vector>
```

and Output is:

[image]

But I want this image in all direction as below:

[image] [image] [image]

### What I have tried:

Added `<vector>` tag in between `<rotate>` but its giving me warning like **`Element vector is not allowed here`**

```
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="90"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toDegrees="90">

    <vector 
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"

        android:viewportWidth="314.015"
        android:viewportHeight="314.015">
        <path
            android:fillColor="#FCD83500"
            android:pathData="M157.007,0C70.291,0 0,70.289 0,157.007c0,86.712 70.29,157.007 157.007,157.007c86.709,0 157.007,-70.295 157.007,-157.007C314.014,70.289 243.716,0 157.007,0zM31.403,157.015c0,-69.373 56.228,-125.613 125.604,-125.613V282.62C87.631,282.62 31.403,226.38 31.403,157.015z" />
    </vector>
</rotate>
```

I have also tried to put `<bitmap>` tag in between `<rotate>` as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:fromDegrees="90"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toDegrees="90">

    <bitmap app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_round" />

</rotate>
```

but its giving me **'src' attribute should be defined** and I can't use `src` with vector images.

Any solution to use this (one image) with all angle?

> NOTE: I want to use this image in `<TextView>` drawable.

Comment: I want to use same file to display on different place with different rotation, how can I use one file to display different rotated state.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Try This Way , I have used the group tag outside of the image path data in vector drawable file.

First Type :

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="24dp"
android:height="24dp"

android:viewportWidth="314.015"
android:viewportHeight="314.015">
<group
    android:translateX="314.015"
    android:rotation="90">
<path
    android:fillColor="#FCD83500"
    android:pathData="M157.007,0C70.291,0 0,70.289 0,157.007c0,86.712 70.29,157.007 157.007,157.007c86.709,0 157.007,-70.295 157.007,-157.007C314.014,70.289 243.716,0 157.007,0zM31.403,157.015c0,-69.373 56.228,-125.613 125.604,-125.613V282.62C87.631,282.62 31.403,226.38 31.403,157.015z" />

</group>
</vector>
```

Second Type :

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="24dp"
android:height="24dp"
android:viewportWidth="314.015"
android:viewportHeight="314.015">
<group
    android:translateX="314"
    android:scaleX="-1"
android:rotation="0">
<path
    android:fillColor="#FCD83500"
    android:pathData="M157.007,0C70.291,0 0,70.289 0,157.007c0,86.712 70.29,157.007 157.007,157.007c86.709,0 157.007,-70.295 157.007,-157.007C314.014,70.289 243.716,0 157.007,0zM31.403,157.015c0,-69.373 56.228,-125.613 125.604,-125.613V282.62C87.631,282.62 31.403,226.38 31.403,157.015z" />
</group>
</vector>
```

Third type:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="24dp"
android:height="24dp"
android:viewportWidth="314.015"
android:viewportHeight="314.015">
<group
    android:translateY="314.015"
    android:rotation="270">
<path
    android:fillColor="#FCD83500"
    android:pathData="M157.007,0C70.291,0 0,70.289 0,157.007c0,86.712 70.29,157.007 157.007,157.007c86.709,0 157.007,-70.295 157.007,-157.007C314.014,70.289 243.716,0 157.007,0zM31.403,157.015c0,-69.373 56.228,-125.613 125.604,-125.613V282.62C87.631,282.62 31.403,226.38 31.403,157.015z" />
</group>
</vector>
```

Comment: @jeevashankar this all three steps are working. but can you tell me the main concept of this? because I need to rotate many sides but don't know how to rotate.

Comment: @BhavenShah it is based on the different angle of rotation logic like [90,0,270,180]

Comment: @jeevashankar where can i learn about group and paths in more detail bro?

Answer (score 57):

For me the best works when using `pivot` of the center of the view.
Please notice that I've used as center half of **viewport** - not width/height

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="36dp"
    android:height="36dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24"
    >

    <group
        android:rotation="45"
        android:pivotY="12"
        android:pivotX="12"
        >
        <path
            android:fillColor="@android:color/white"
            android:pathData="M19,13h-6v6h-2v-6H5v-2h6V5h2v6h6v2z"
            />
    </group>

</vector>
```

Comment: This answer worked for me rather than an accepted answer. Thanks a lot man

Comment: Thanks alot..It worked   !

Comment: Much cleaner way than the accepted answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

For those looking for the fourth variant, to flip something upside down, 
the code looks like this:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:width="24dp"
  android:height="24dp"
  android:viewportWidth="24.0"
  android:viewportHeight="24.0">
  <group
    android:translateY="24.0"
    android:scaleY="-1"
    android:rotation="0">
    <path
      android:fillColor="#FF000000"
      android:pathData="M1,21h4L5,9L1,9v12zM23,10c0,-1.1 -0.9,-2 -2,-2h-6.31l0.95,-4.57 0.03,-0.32c0,-0.41 -0.17,-0.79 -0.44,-1.06L14.17,1 7.59,7.59C7.22,7.95 7,8.45 7,9v10c0,1.1 0.9,2 2,2h9c0.83,0 1.54,-0.5 1.84,-1.22l3.02,-7.05c0.09,-0.23 0.14,-0.47 0.14,-0.73v-1.91l-0.01,-0.01L23,10z"/>
  </group>
</vector>
```

Answer (score 6):

In fact you can not rotate vector.xml because it drawn by pathData,
unless you do it in another combination.

you can separate TextView and ImageView and use it like this:

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Set time"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/close_dialog"
            android:layout_width="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:rotation="45"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_close_black_24dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a solution. its only trick and it will increase my line of code.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to rotate like a mirror image, Add android:scaleY="-1",android:translateY

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:width="24dp"
 android:height="24dp"
 android:viewportWidth="24"
 android:viewportHeight="24">
  <group
    android:scaleY="-1"
    android:translateY="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:pathData="M12 2L2 12L12 22"
        android:strokeWidth="2.5"
        android:strokeColor="#ffffff"
        android:strokeLineCap="round" />
 </group>
</vector>
```