# Android How to draw a half circle

Tags: java, android, kotlin, view, draw

I would like to draw half circles like in the image attached below. I also would like to give the half circles a position (x,y start and end) and set the color and line width.

[image]

I have been searching a lot but I did not find a solution that can help me.

Comment: Please check this
[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31705870/how-to-draw-a-half-circle-in-android/31706849)

Comment: Thank you, but I need a solution so I can set the position, therefore also the size prgrammatically